# Not able to add URL to my intelliji for my git

Tags: java, git

Image of the exact problem

[image: Image of the exact problem]

> Remote URL test failed: Authentication failed for ...

Why does IntelliJ refuses to add this URL and does not even ask me for my credentials (login/password)?

Comment: Please read [ask]. A screenshot by itself isn't a very good question. At the very least, tell is what error message you are seeing (as text, not just in your screenshot). It looks like you have an authentication error; are you _entirely sure_ you're using the right credentials?

Comment: First thing I'd do is remove that trailing forward-slash

Comment: @Chris The question behind the picture was quite clear to me: I have edited the post to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have a credential helper (set to manager)

```
git config credential.helper
```

That could have cached the wrong credentials, and would be automatically picked up by Git within IntelliJ.

You would need to remove the entry for that remote in the Windows Credential Manager, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/6309).

Comment: @Ash Please consider accepting this answer to avoid your question to be automatically deleted (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)